# Inserting Values to Non Abstract Methods in Abstract Class Using a Sub Non Abstract Class

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

I want to access and use 3 private variables in an Abstract Class(MainAbstract.java) from another class that has extended (SubAbstract.java) from the previously mentioned Abstract Class.

From the sub class I want to access the getters() and setters() of the main class's.

In the main class (this is an abstract class) there is an abstract method called ShowInfo().

This ShowInfo() abstract method should do something to view the each instance of the subclass's.

Below is the source code for the MainClass(Abstract) and the Sub Class SubAbstract. Please refer them.

***MainAbstract.java***

```
package abstractionexample;
public abstract class MainAbstract {

    private String sName;
    private String sType;
    private int iQty;

     public String getsName() {
        return sName;
     }

     public void setsName(String sName) {
         this.sName = sName;
      }

     public String getsType() {
        return sType;
      }

     public void setsType(String sType) {
        this.sType = sType;
     }

      public int getiQty() {
         return iQty;
     }

       public void setiQty(int iQty) {
           this.iQty = iQty;
       }

        public abstract void showInfo();

        public static void main(String[] args) {       

      }
  }
```

***SubAbstract.java***

```
package abstractionexample;

public class SubAbstract extends MainAbstract{

   @Override
    public void showInfo() {

    }

     //This is an instance and the getters() and setters() should use each    instance of this kind of to get values and set values.
     SubAbstract nSubAbs = new SubAbstract();  

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But you cannot access `private` members from any external class including sub classes.

Comment: You are correct! That's why I used getters() and setters(). I am trying to find a possibility to do the trick.

Comment: As long as your showInfo() method stays empty, nothing is shown of course. What do you expect?

Comment: As the question implied, I want to use the getters() and setters() in the MainAbstract class from SubAbstract class. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the setter methods to set properties of the instance `nSubAbs` and show these properties using the `showInfo()` method.

The getters and setters are **readily available** to you in your subclass `SubAbstract` because it has inherited from the parent class `MainAbstract`

Here's a code sample:

```
class SubAbstract extends MainAbstract{

    SubAbstract nSubAbs;

    SubAbstract(int iQty, String name, String type) {
        nSubAbs = new SubAbstract();
        this.nSubAbs.setiQty(iQty);
        this.nSubAbs.setsName(name);
        this.nSubAbs.setsType(type);
    }

    private SubAbstract() {
        //no arg constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("iQty:" + nSubAbs.getiQty());
        System.out.println("name:" + nSubAbs.getsName());
        System.out.println("type:" + nSubAbs.getsType());
    }
}
```

And the main method of your MainAbstract class would look something like this (although this is a very bad place for the main method, but I suppose, you are trying to experiment)

```
public abstract class MainAbstract {

    //..existing code..

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SubAbstract subAbstract = new SubAbstract(10, "someName", "someType");
        subAbstract.showInfo();
    }
}
```